# SQL Management Studio and TFS

Tags: sql-server-2008, msscci

I'm trying to setup TFS 2010 integration for SQL Management studio 2008. I've installed MSSCCI and managed to create a ssmssln file and add it to TFS, however I don't see any options to add the SQL files to TFS from SQL Management studio 2008. I, configured the scource control plugin under Tools->Options for SQL Management studio.

Should the MSSCCI provider give me the ability to check sql scripts in and out of TFS?

If so what do I need to do in order to add files to TFS from within SQL Management studio

Thanks
Alan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this possibility is given with TFS & SQL. It's possible to do this with external addins, like the [Redgate SQL Toolbelt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/).

We don't use such addin, instead:
- We have a database solution containing a *.dbproj checked-in in TFS
- The very same DB is deployed on an SQL-Server
- We make our changes in the DB-implementation in SSMS
- We sync the source controlled DB-Solution with the one residing in SQL server using the 'Data' tools provided in VS.