# How can we integrate SQL Server Management Studio 2008 with TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2008-r2, integration, ssms

We want to maintain our sql server scripts history. What is the solution? can we integrate SQL Server Management Studio 2008 with TFS 2010?

Comment: Check if this is a duplicate-helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815065/sql-management-studio-and-tfs

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there is, a DB professional which is a project type in the visual studio, this type of project will maintain DB objects as separate files so it can be treated as normal C# or VB file, for version control.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SSMS is able to save sql files to SCCI compliant source control systems, such as TFS. [Here is an article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1962-using-the-tfs-as-a-source-control-repository-for-ssms-projects.aspx) explaining how to achieve this.

However, this just saves sql files but doesn't assist in the versioning of the schema objects in your database. Should you need to do this, [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/), which we have developed at Red Gate, allows you to connect your SQL Server instance in SSMS to your back-end source control system, such as TFS.

Answer (score -1):

How exactly does that integrate with SSMS???  You can still go behind the scenes with ssms and edit whatever you want, regardless of source control.

Comment: Please ask for clarification in question comments. Your answer in current form doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: Agreed. I suspect that George meant to comment on M.Radwan's answer.